# Strategery - InfiniteScroll Not Working

Tags: php, magento, infinite-scroll, magento-1.9

I wanted to implement infinite scrolling in my magento website so I installed the  Strategery - InfiniteScroll extension but it is not working, first I thought it is because I still have pagination, but even after removing the paging toolbar it is not working.
I removed those toolbar divs

```
<div class="toolbar-top">
    <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
</div>
```

from top and bottom. 
Can you please help me to configure Strategery - InfiniteScroll extension?

Comment: Have you had checked the console log. Is there any error exists?

Comment: yes, it is  Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: listing":"<div class=\"category-products\">\r\n ....and there is huge code..

Comment: After a lot of search i found that for loading next items it expects html response but instead it is getting a json response..

Comment: @MaX did you get any solution for this issue?

Comment: can you please share a site link here?

Comment: did you installed correctly ? how did u install the extension ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From https://github.com/Strategery-Inc/Magento-InfiniteScroll/wiki/Installation-under-a-different-package---theme:

> If you copy the 'infinitescroll' folder on your webroot, the files
>   will end up under the default theme. This should be ok in most
>   installations because Magento falls back to the default theme when it
>   can find files in the custom themes. The rest of this article covers
>   the scenario where the plugin isn't loaded correctly from the default
>   package/theme.
>
> The first thing you should do is move them to the package/theme you're
>   using, just to be sure they'll be loaded.
>
> 1. Browse the repository to see where the files are located. Those that are inside the 'app/design/frontend/default/default' should be
>      moved to your package/theme: 'app/design/frontend/package/theme'.
> 2. Visit the following url: http://www.yourwebsite.com/infinitescroll2/js and make sure there's
>      some Javascript being printed. If you get a 404 then the module is not
>      loaded properly. If its blank or you get an exception then the module
>      probably has trouble finding the layout or template files.
> 3. Once the URL above returns javascript, visit a page in your catalog and view its source. Make sure you can find the following
>      string within the source: "infinitescroll/js" - it should exist as
>      part of the URL for a SCRIPT tag. If you can't find it then you have a
>      compatibility problem with the layout file (which in the repository is
>      located at
>      app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/strategery-infinitescroll.xml).
> 4. If the string exists however then the plugin is loaded and configured properly.
> 5. Finally, once you know the plugin is being loaded, you will have to adjust the options under System -> Configuration -> Catalog ->
>      Infinite Scroll in order to configure InfiniteScroll options properly.
>       You will find two types of selectors. The first one is the container, by default called "category-products", which "contains" all
>      the items. category-products
>
> Then you will find another selector called "products-grid" which is
>   the item selector. item
>
> This two selectors are the ones you must enter in the Infinite Scroll
>   configuration under Content and Items.category-products
>
> Next: next
>
> You can get the code by doing a second click on the screen and picking
>   "Inspect element" in any modern browser.
>
> For this extension to work with any theme, the theme must have a
>   container div, like category-products and also a item div like
>   products-grid.
>
> Also the theme must have the pager active, otherwise the extension
>   wont work because of the lack of some selectors.
>
> For more information on how to configure the options follow this link:
>   http://www.infinite-scroll.com/infinite-scroll-jquery-plugin/
>
> OR
>
> If problem not solved then
>
> After the installation
>
> 1. Add the following in layout.xml:
>
>    strategery/infinitescroll/init.phtml
> 2. Copy from app/design/frontend/base/default/template/strategery path to the same path in your theme
> 3. Copy from skin/frontend/base/default/js/infinitescroll path to the same path in your skin-theme
> 4. Make sure that the /js/jquery/infinitescroll path exist and have four *.js files inside
> 5. Configure plugin:
>
>    - always set Yes on Include jQuery field
>    - always view that your product-list div class is same as in Content field. In default theme is ".category-products" class (with the dot is
>        a first sign in class name)
>    - always set No on Hide Toolbar field
> 6. Of cource you should flash all possible cache :) If not working - do this:
> 7. On the page set grid mode manually an you can see "mode=grid" in url. Thats all, guys :)

Comment: second point is not working,
But still it shows me "Congratulations, you've reached the end of the internet" so I think infinitescroll is loaded correctly

But Infinite scroll is not triggering more product or not showing load more button

Answer (score 0):

Cause of some extensions that modify the output of the system in JSON and not in HTML - I solved it this way:
in JQuery-ias.js, on line 340

```
return $.get(loadEvent.url, null, $.proxy(function(data) {
            $itemContainer = $(this.itemsContainerSelector, data).eq(0);
            if (0 === $itemContainer.length) {
                $itemContainer = $(data).filter(this.itemsContainerSelector).eq(0);
            }

            if ($itemContainer) {
                $itemContainer.find(this.itemSelector).each(function() {
                    items.push(this);
                });
            }

            self.fire('loaded', [data, items]);

            if (callback) {
                timeDiff = +new Date() - timeStart;
                if (timeDiff < delay) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        callback.call(self, data, items);
                    }, delay - timeDiff);
                } else {
                    callback.call(self, data, items);
                }
            }
        }, self), 'html');
```

I've changed it like this:

```
return $.get(loadEvent.url, null, $.proxy(function(data) {
                data = data['maincontent']; // HERE TO CATCH THE RIGHT HTML CONTENT
                $itemContainer = $(this.itemsContainerSelector, data).eq(0);
                if (0 === $itemContainer.length) {
                    $itemContainer = $(data).filter(this.itemsContainerSelector).eq(0);
                }

                if ($itemContainer) {
                    $itemContainer.find(this.itemSelector).each(function() {
                        items.push(this);
                    });
                }

                self.fire('loaded', [data, items]);

                if (callback) {
                    timeDiff = +new Date() - timeStart;
                    if (timeDiff < delay) {
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            callback.call(self, data, items);
                        }, delay - timeDiff);
                    } else {
                        callback.call(self, data, items);
                    }
                }
            }, self), 'json'); // I've changed html by JSon
```